# Custom css code in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Can someone maybe help me with a few lines of css code?

I would like to my search section on my page:

http://www.virtual-forms.com/docs/

To look something like this:
https://docs.wedevs.com/

I'm new to CSS and Wordpress
Thanks, Davor

**EDIT:**
My latest try was with this:

```
/*Header search weDocs*/
.wedocs input[type="submit"],
.wedocs input[type="search"]
{
    background-color: #fff !important;
    color: #000;
    width: 50%;
}
```

But no luck.

Comment: Please post a more specific question, with a code snippet. Also consider posting WordPress questions to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @NathanielFlick. This is a general CSS question, not a lot a wordpress related. I'm looking for help to add the CSS code that would change the 3 elements (search-field (textbox), search_in_doc (combobox) and search-submit (button)). First to align them inline, and then to change the appearance to look like the one on this another page.

Comment: @NathanielFlick. I have ask this question there. Should I try to delete it here?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for *specific programming questions*. You are expected to at least attempt to solve your issue and include a summary of what you have tried so far and a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Come back if you have a **specific** css question after you've tried for yourself

Comment: thanks @FluffyKitten I have tried a lot of combinations in the custom css, also using important! but obviously, I can not get the right class or div.

Comment: If you post the code you have tried, we might be able to find the issue you are having and help get it the way you  would like. But SO is not a code-writing service so no one is going to do it all for you :-)

Comment: My latest code with which I'm trying to find if I'm on a good track is this: /* Header search weDocs*/
.wedocs input[type="submit"],
.wedocs input[type="search"]
{
    background-color: #fff !important;
    color: #000;
    width: 50%;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get on with applying correct CSS by inspecting the elements in your web browser (right-click element on site > Inspect) to find their correct classes. inspecting linked site virtual-forms.com shows that the whole search form has a parent form element with class="search-form wedocs-search-form", with child divs with classes "wedocs-search-input" for input, "wedocs-search-in" for dropdown and "search-submit" for submit-button.

I would put display: flex; on the parent element:

```
.wedocs-search-form {
    display: flex;
}
```

use classes to style each individual element there

```
.wedocs-search-input { }
.wedocs-search-in { }
.search-submit { }
```

Using those classes should get you closer to getting the correct style to those elements. read up on the flexbox here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I would use flex-grow on input to make it bigger for example. Hope this gets you along.